# Method Range of Object Failed - Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply some formatting conditions to an entire row where in a cell of a specific column the value is zero.

However the output is the "Method Range of Object Failed" error and cannot understand why:

```
Dim MyNewRange As Range
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = 26
ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1)

For Each cell In MyRange
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        cell.FormatConditions.Delete
        Set MyNewRange = ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ColLetter & cell.Row)
        MyNewRange.Select
    End If
Next cell
```

Thanks

Comment: `"A" & cell.Row & ColLetter & cell.Row` would result in something like `A1X1` which is not proper range address, you are missing a colon

Comment: Use basic debugging: try `Debug.Print "A" & cell.Row & ColLetter & cell.Row` right before the offending line and see what you get. You will see that @avb has correctly diagnosed the problem.

Comment: Or easier yet just replace the second `&` with a `,` (comma).

Comment: `ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ColLetter & cell.Row)` should be `ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":" &  ColLetter & cell.Row)`

Comment: Thanks guys I ended up with Set MyNewRange = ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":" & ColLetter & cell.Row). I forgot to add a colon, thanks

Comment: Why use `ColLetter` when you can e.g. do `ws.Range("A" & cell.Row, ws.Cells(cell.Row, LastColumn))`. Also, you can do `ws.Range(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "A"), ws.Cells(cell.row, LastColumn))` or `ws.Range(ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1), ws.Cells(cell.row, LastColumn))`. Even  `ws.Cells(cell.Row, "A"),Resize(, LastColumn)` or `ws.Range("A" & cell.Row).Resize(, LastColumn)` since the first column is column `A`.